# Variable containing list of values to be saved in an excel using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to python and trying my luck, 
I have a Json to extract particular items and those items will be saved in variables and using FOR loop i'm displaying the entire json data as a output.
Basically, I want the entire output console in an excel with the help of dataframe(Panda) or if there is alternative way much appreciable.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('i4.json', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f:
data = json.load(f)

for ib in data['documents']:
tit = ib['title']
stat = ib['status']
print(tit, stat)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title' : [tit], 'Status' : [stat]})
df.to_excel('fromSIM.xls', index= False)
```

Output is: (Ex:)

```
title1 pass
title2 fail
```

The problem with excel is: 
Am getting the excel saved as below,

```
Title   Status
title2  fail
```

Anyone can en-light the above code to make all the output to be saved in the excel below each values one by one

Comment: Please,  could you indent your code?

Comment: updated above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the data frame in each loop iteration. You should create the data frame out of the `for`, and thus only append the new rows in the DF inside the `for`.

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Title', 'Status']
df_ = pd.DataFrame( columns=columns)
for ib in data['documents']:

    tit = ib['title']
    stat = ib['status']
    print(tit, stat)
    df_ = df_.append(pd.Series([tit,stat], index=df_.columns ), ignore_index=True)

df_.to_excel('fromSIM.xls', index= False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply!  I tried your code but i am getting this error code:     df_ = df_.append(pd.Series([tit,stat], index=df_.columns), ignore_index= True)
                                                                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: error in this line: 
df_ = df_.append(pd.Series([tit,stat], index=df_.columns ), ignore_index=True)

Comment: This isn't code error. It's about indentation. Check if all indentations are correcto.

Comment: sure.. your contribution really helps :)